# AssertionError: `assert not _is_device_list_single_worker(devices)` while training estimator on ai-platform with mirrored strategy with TF 2.1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm running a training job on gcp ai-platform for tensorflow estimators with mirrored distribution strategy with `--python-version 3.7` and `--runtime-version 2.1`.

I'm providing the necessary code snippet below:

```py
SESS_CONFIG = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
    allow_soft_placement=True,
    log_device_placement=False,
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=0,
    gpu_options=tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(force_gpu_compatible=True))

config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=10,
                   save_checkpoints_steps=20,
                   session_config=SESS_CONFIG,
                   keep_checkpoint_max=5,
                   log_step_count_steps=100,
                   train_distribute=tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(), # Distribution Strategy
                   eval_distribute=tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(),  # Distribution Strategy
                   experimental_max_worker_delay_secs=None)

# -----------

custom_estimator_model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn(), model_dir=model_dir,
        config=config)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_fn,
                                    max_steps=train_steps)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn,
                                  steps=eval_steps,
                                  exporters=exporters,
                                  throttle_secs=eval_throttle_secs)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(custom_estimator_model,
                                train_spec,
                                eval_spec)
```

Config: `config.yaml` used:

```yaml
trainingInput:
  masterType: complex_model_m_gpu
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
```

The code **was working** on ai-platform with tensorflow 1.14 and Python 3.5 and in `RunConfig()` the strategy was provided as `train_distribute=tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`. But after TF2 upgrade it was changed to `train_distribute=tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`.
After this changed the error is:

Error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 239, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 235, in main
    model_dir=model_dir)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/models/models.py", line 244, in train_from_scratch
    self.train_estimator(model_dir)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/models/models.py", line 234, in train_estimator
    eval_spec)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 463, in train_and_evaluate
    _TrainingExecutor)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/estimator_training.py", line 290, in train_and_evaluate
    session_config=run_config.session_config)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_coordinator.py", line 836, in run_distribute_coordinator
    task_type, task_id)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_coordinator.py", line 548, in _configure_session_config_for_std_servers
    task_id=task_id)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1127, in configure
    session_config, cluster_spec, task_type, task_id)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py", line 788, in _configure
    self._initialize_multi_worker(multi_worker_devices)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py", line 510, in _initialize_multi_worker
    device_dict = _group_device_list(devices)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py", line 265, in _group_device_list
    assert not _is_device_list_single_worker(devices)
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem when I upgraded from runtime 1.5 to 2.3 using mirrored strategy.

It seems that the default configuration for the master has changed (see [chief-versus-master](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/distributed-training-details#chief-versus-master)) which causes tf to fail with this error when it tries to configure the cordinator with a single worker.
For us the solution was to unset the TF_CONFIG (`del os.environ["TF_CONFIG"]`), which caused it to fall back to the previous behavior.

Comment: We actually went back to tf1 due to many such issues